# Я бросил деньги ему в лицо и сказал, что он может забирать их и уходить(,) или я убью его

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> Я бросил деньги ему в лицо и сказал, что он может забирать их и уходить(,) или я убью его.

Нужна ли запятая перед "или"? На [аск.фм сказали](https://ask.fm/russian/threads/155250118972), что нужна, но ситуация спорная.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Я бросил деньги ему в лицо и сказал, **что он может забирать их и уходить или я убью его.***

Запятая не ставится между однородными изъяснительными придаточными, соединенными одиночным разделительным союзом ИЛИ.

Розенталь

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=139#pp139

3. Между однородными придаточными частями сложноподчиненного предложения, связанными неповторяющимися союзами (соединительными или **разделительными**) запятая не ставится.